# Java App with Derby DB and SQL Exception

Tags: java, database, derby

I need help!
I created Java Stand Alone Application via NetBeans with embedded derby db. My problem is that when I install app on another machine that uses win8 and win 10 first time when I enter app I can create,update,delete values from db. Everything seems to works fine untill I close my app and start it again. When I start it again created data is there but when I try to add new data,update or delete data I get SQLException"
"An SQL data change is not permitted for read-only connection,user or database" .
Everything works fine in winXp,winVista and Win7.

Comment: File permissions, perhaps? But ... seriously ... this question lacks any information that could be helpful for troubleshooting. How should anyone help you with such a vague problem description? At least, tell us the whole exception stack trace. And I think, there must be much more (Directory layout, startup mechanism, ...). This is a very poor question, sorry.

Comment: it's quite difficult to get whole exception stack trace cause I'm running desktop app, in my project everything works fine so I cant get stackTrace.

I think it's problem with permissions, cause I should probably create root user with password and full access control. Probably when I try to modify db Im not logged as root user cause in my case right now root user doesnt exist.

Thanks anyway. I will try to print stackTrace.

Comment: DataBase is in READ ONLY mode. Do anyone have idea how to solve this problem.?!